# error: failed linking file resources: Daemon: AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-alpha14-4748712-linux Daemon #0

Tags: android

I'm aware this question has been asked now and again but I don't understand any of the answers that have been provided, maybe it's because they are not so relevant to my error.

I getting the error below after building my Gradle in my Android Studio project:

```
Android resource linking failed
```

Output:

```
W/ResourceType( 2455): For resource 0x0101053d, entry index(1341) is beyond type entryCount(1329)
W/ResourceType( 2455): For resource 0x0101053e, entry index(1342) is beyond type entryCount(1329)
W/ResourceType( 2455): For resource 0x0101053b, entry index(1339) is beyond type entryCount(1329)
W/ResourceType( 2455): For resource 0x0101053c, entry index(1340) is beyond type entryCount(1329)
/home/sakhile/Downloads/ud851-Exercises-student/Lesson03-Green-Recycler-View/Tasker/app/src/main/res/layout/service_list.xml:47: error: attribute android:textinearLayoutStyle not found.
error: failed linking file resources.

Command: /home/sakhile/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha14-4748712-linux.jar/1d98a9485ac4d9eebc41ea1399977a49/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha14-4748712-linux/aapt2 link -I\
        /home/sakhile/Downloads/Sdk/platforms/android-25/android.jar\
        --manifest\
        /home/sakhile/Downloads/ud851-Exercises-student/Lesson03-Green-Recycler-View/Tasker/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        /home/sakhile/Downloads/ud851-Exercises-student/Lesson03-Green-Recycler-View/Tasker/app/build/intermediates/processed_res/debug/processDebugResources/out/resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @/home/sakhile/Downloads/ud851-Exercises-student/Lesson03-Green-Recycler-View/Tasker/app/build/intermediates/incremental/processDebugResources/resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        /home/sakhile/Downloads/ud851-Exercises-student/Lesson03-Green-Recycler-View/Tasker/app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r\
        --custom-package\
        com.example.sakhile.tasker\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        /home/sakhile/Downloads/ud851-Exercises-student/Lesson03-Green-Recycler-View/Tasker/app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug/R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-alpha14-4748712-linux Daemon #0
```

Comment: Attribute android:textinearLayoutStyle not found in service_list.xml. Looks like a typo, but what is this attribute?

Answer (score 0):

In your layout `service_list.xml` you're trying to use an android attribute `android:textinearLayoutStyle`. First of all it looks like you've done a typo, but secondly there's no similar android attribute that you could be refering to. Did you perhaps mean to use `android:textStyle`?